# How Can I scroll to the last message in my app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, scroll

please a little help. I'm kind of new to flutter and I'e been able to implement firebase and it's all working. I have a chat app and I'm trying to ensure the app automatically scrolls to the last message all the time, please is there any suggestions. I have the code here for the message wall, If you need any more info please let me know:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'chat_message_other.dart';
import 'chat_message.dart';

class MessageWall extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> messages;
  final ValueChanged<String> onDelete;

  const MessageWall({
    Key key,
    this.messages,
    this.onDelete,
  }) : super(key: key);

  bool shouldDisplayAvatar(int idx) {
    if (idx == 0) return true;

    final previousId = messages[idx - 1].data()['author_id'];
    final authorId = messages[idx].data()['author_id'];
    return authorId != previousId;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: messages.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final data = messages[index].data();
        final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

        if (user != null && user.uid == data['author_id']) {
          return Dismissible(
            onDismissed: (_) {
              onDelete(messages[index].id);
            },
            key: ValueKey(data['timestamp']),
            child: ChatMessage(
              index: index,
              data: data,
            ),
          );
        }

        return ChatMessageOther(
          index: index,
          data: data,
          showAvatar: shouldDisplayAvatar(index),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ScrollController`

- Definition

  ```
  final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  ```
- Combine

  ```
  ListView.builder(
    controller:controller
  );
  ```
- Usage (Whenever user send a message)

  ```
  controller.animateTo(
     0.0,
     duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), 
     curve: Curves.easeOut,
  );
  ```

Answer (score 1):

set `reverse` to `true` in the `ListView`

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'chat_message_other.dart';
import 'chat_message.dart';

class MessageWall extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> messages;
  final ValueChanged<String> onDelete;

  const MessageWall({
    Key key,
    this.messages,
    this.onDelete,
  }) : super(key: key);

  bool shouldDisplayAvatar(int idx) {
    if (idx == 0) return true;

    final previousId = messages[idx - 1].data()['author_id'];
    final authorId = messages[idx].data()['author_id'];
    return authorId != previousId;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: messages.length,
      reverse:true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final data = messages[index].data();
        final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

        if (user != null && user.uid == data['author_id']) {
          return Dismissible(
            onDismissed: (_) {
              onDelete(messages[index].id);
            },
            key: ValueKey(data['timestamp']),
            child: ChatMessage(
              index: index,
              data: data,
            ),
          );
        }

        return ChatMessageOther(
          index: index,
          data: data,
          showAvatar: shouldDisplayAvatar(index),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s very simple to achieve this functionality,
Let me explain little bit:

```
When you use any scrollable widgets for 
 Eg: listview, singlechildscrollview ,grid view etc
```

All of them are scrolled either top to bottom or left to
Right but in some use case we have to scroll in opposite direction like in case of whatsapp.

So if have one property name  :-

```
           reverse : true (by default false)
```

That’s all I hope it’s helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ends up here, and the other solutions don't work... Don't forget to sort your query from Firebase DESCENDING!!  I struggled with this for 3 days off and on, before I realized I wanted to sort my data descending so that index 0 is my newest message (largest timestamp).